# PHP add first table column id to another table column id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

There are 2 Table in the Database.

1. tbl_second_category
   [image]
2. tbl_third_category[image]

I'm already passing 
**col_first_category_id** 
from 
**table1 tbl_second_category** 
to 
**Table2 tbl_third_category** **col_second_category_id**
using select box control 
You can see **id 13** in both the Tables

when I'm passing above id, at the same time how can I pass **col_second_category_id** from Table1
**tbl_second_category** to column **col_for_delete_row** Table2 **tbl_third_category**.

Thank you

Comment: question is unclear.. you could do it same way as you did for col_second_category_id

Comment: we don't have to trigger any control, it should work in the background

Answer (score 0):

then use [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html), you may need more then one for update and delete events... for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON tbl_second_category
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE tbl_third_category
SET col_for_delete_row  = NEW.col_second_category_id
WHERE col_second_category_id = NEW.col_first_category_id;
```